# List from local storage is null after navigating to a new page

Tags: flutter, dart

Am trying to get list from local storage like so :

```
var list;
  var ListTypes;

  final LocalStorage storage = new LocalStorage('deepnrise');

  getStorage() async {
    await storage.ready;
    list = storage.getItem('todos');
    ListTypes = storage.getItem('typeSettingsList');
  }

  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    setState(() {
      getStorage();
    });
  }
```

When I run the app it works fine but when I navigate to another page and back to the list page I get the following error

```
The getter 'isNotEmpty' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: isNotEmpty
```

```
 The getter 'isNotEmpty' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: isNotEmpty
```

am using the list am getting like so :

```
 if (list.isNotEmpty) {
      print("list from storage $list");
      return ListView.builder(
          physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemCount: list.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            String? _setImage() {
              String? backgroundImage;
              setTypeLabel(index);
              if (list[index].typeName == "Delivery") {
                backgroundImage = "assets/icons/delivery.png";
              } else if (list[index].typeName == "Security") {
                backgroundImage = "assets/icons/security.png";
              } else if (list[index].typeName == "Quality") {
                backgroundImage = "assets/icons/quality.png";
              } else if (list[index].typeName == "Cost") {
                backgroundImage = "assets/icons/Cost.png";
              } else if (list[index].typeName == "People") {
                backgroundImage = "assets/icons/people.png";
              } else {
                backgroundImage = "assets/icons/unknown.png";
              }
              return backgroundImage;
            }

            return Column(
              children: [
                ConditionalBuilder(
                    condition: list[index].status == 'INIT',
                    builder: (context) => QrqcBody(
                          child: QrqcCard(
                              child: QrqcCardBody(
                            color: Colors.orange,
                            text: list[index].status,
                            leading: QrqcCardLeaing(imgPath: _setImage()),
                            trailing: QrqcCardtrailing(
                              text: list[index].progress.toString(),
                              percent: list[index].progress.toString(),
                            ),
                            title: list[index].id.toString(),
                            subtitle: list[index].title,
                            chlidren: [
                              QrqcDetailsCardFirstRow(
                                product:
                                    list[index].productName ?? 'no product',
                                role: list[index].role ?? "no role",
                              ),
                              const SizedBox(height: 10),
                              QrqcDetailsCardSecondRow(
                                perim: list[index].perimeterName ?? "no perim",
                                date: convertDateTimeDisplay(
                                    list[index].createdAt!),
                              ),
                              const SizedBox(height: 10),
                            ],
                          )),
                        ),
                    fallback: null),
                ConditionalBuilder(
                    condition: list[index].status == 'SUBMITTED',
                    builder: (context) => QrqcBody(
                          child: QrqcCard(
                              child: QrqcCardBody(
                            color: Colors.blue,
                            text: 'SUB',
                            leading: QrqcCardLeaing(imgPath: _setImage()),
                            trailing: QrqcCardtrailing(
                              text: list[index].progress.toString(),
                              percent: list[index].progress.toString(),
                            ),
                            title: list[index].id.toString(),
                            subtitle: list[index].title,
                            chlidren: [
                              QrqcDetailsCardFirstRow(
                                product:
                                    list[index].productName ?? 'no product',
                                role: list[index].role ?? "no role",
                              ),
                              const SizedBox(height: 10),
                              QrqcDetailsCardSecondRow(
                                perim: list[index].perimeterName ?? "no perim",
                                date: convertDateTimeDisplay(
                                    list[index].createdAt!),
                              ),
                              const SizedBox(height: 10),
                            ],
                          )),
                        ),
                    fallback: null),
                ConditionalBuilder(
                    condition: list[index].status == 'VALIDATED',
                    builder: (context) => QrqcBody(
                          child: QrqcCard(
                              child: QrqcCardBody(
                            color: Colors.green,
                            text: 'VALID',
                            leading: QrqcCardLeaing(imgPath: _setImage()),
                            trailing: QrqcCardtrailing(
                              text: list[index].progress.toString(),
                              percent: list[index].progress.toString(),
                            ),
                            title: list[index].id.toString(),
                            subtitle: list[index].title,
                            chlidren: [
                              QrqcDetailsCardFirstRow(
                                product: 'fromoff',
                                role: list[index].role ?? "no role",
                              ),
                              const SizedBox(height: 10),
                              QrqcDetailsCardSecondRow(
                                perim: list[index].perimeterName ?? "no perim",
                                date: convertDateTimeDisplay(
                                    list[index].createdAt!),
                              ),
                              const SizedBox(height: 10),
                            ],
                          )),
                        ),
                    fallback: null),
                ConditionalBuilder(
                    condition: list[index].status == 'ESCALATED',
                    builder: (context) => QrqcBody(
                          child: QrqcCard(
                              child: QrqcCardBody(
                            color: Colors.red,
                            text: 'ESCAL',
                            leading: QrqcCardLeaing(imgPath: _setImage()),
                            trailing: QrqcCardtrailing(
                              text: list[index].progress.toString(),
                              percent: list[index].progress.toString(),
                            ),
                            title: list[index].id.toString(),
                            subtitle: list[index].title,
                            chlidren: [
                              QrqcDetailsCardFirstRow(
                                product:
                                    list[index].productName ?? 'no product',
                                role: list[index].role ?? "no role",
                              ),
                              const SizedBox(height: 10),
                              QrqcDetailsCardSecondRow(
                                perim: list[index].perimeterName ?? "no perim",
                                date: convertDateTimeDisplay(
                                    list[index].createdAt!),
                              ),
                              const SizedBox(height: 10),
                            ],
                          )),
                        ),
                    fallback: null)
              ],
            );
          });
    } else if (list.isEmpty) {
      return const NoDataUI();
    }
    return const Center(
      child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
    );
```

Where did I go wrong ? I've read somewhere that I have to check if storage is ready before using it , so I did so . Why is it causing the list to become null after navigating to a new page or closing the app ? if anyone has an answer please do help me thank you in advance

Comment: where you put the logic for navigation to next page..??

Comment: I've been able to keep the data from page to page but when I close the app and reopen it , data gets lost

Comment: why you are not using sharedpreferences to store data locally..??

Answer (score 0):

I think your data is presist in local database ..but it take some time to fetch data from database. and at that time your app load and it cant find data . so please use below code .first make your getStorge method to future.

```
 Future getStorage() async {
    await storage.ready;
    list = storage.getItem('todos');
    ListTypes = storage.getItem('typeSettingsList');
  }

  @override
  void initState() {

    WidgetsBinding.instance?.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
      setState(() {
    await  getStorage();
    });

    });

    super.initState();
  }
```

Comment: if you find that solution helpful. then please mark my solution as accepted answer